# Are duplicate Greek PLFs required to provide accurate vaccination information?

Tags: covid-19, greece, vaccinations

I was trying to fill in the [Greek PLF](https://travel.gov.gr/) for entry into the country tomorrow. Now, I noticed that despite the form asking for the number of people in my household, it did not give me any options to enter the vaccination details for the other people in my household (we differ in everything, including date of vaccination and type of vaccine used). **Does this mean that we should still submit different PLFs (one for both of us) to provide the Greek authorities with our details?**

I should add that as part of the declaration, I had to check a checkbox that said "Only one PLF will be submitted per household", which I obviously checked, but I was expecting to be able to fill in all of  the details for both of us.

Comment: Do you have more information on this topic now ?

Comment: @Kii: Yes and no. The Greek authorities didn't check anyone from our plane on disembarkation, but both of us did fill in the forms. Therefore, not sure what the actual correct way of doing this is. I believe that the airline attendant did ask about this, and they were happy with both of us having the forms.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) Leaving tomorrow. I'll add whatever intel I can grasp. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.